# How do i convert a binary int into a string?

Tags: c

I'm looking to convert an integer representation of binary into a string. i'm not allowed to use bitwise operations.
when i converted the decimal integer value into that integer binary representation, i could've put the digits in a string and reverse, but i'm searching for a more elegant way.

Any ideas?

Comment: actually, all the numbers are represented in binary at CPU level, means when you type `int a = 5`, the value of `a` is viewed as `101`.
unless you provide an example, this question is not clear.

Comment: You are confused. An integer is not binary (or octal, or decimal). It can be *represented* in binary (or octal), or in English (e.g. `five` is the same as `0b101` in binary, or `5` in decimal).

Answer (score 3):

If you can't use bitwise operators just divide by 2 and check the reminder, you don't need to reverse the string if you use a fixed size (i.e. 32), something like:

```
/* Only for positive numbers */

char bin[] = "00000000000000000000000000000000";
int count = 31, num = 25;

while (num) {
    if (num % 2) bin[count] = '1';
    num /= 2;
    count--;
}
printf("%s\n", bin);
```